# Multiple .colptr in Armadillo

Tags: pointers, armadillo

In Armadillo, there is a pointer to a single column by using `.colptr( col_number )`. So, we can write, for example,

```
mat X(nrow, ncol);
vec y(X.colptr(0), nrow, false, true);
X.col(0) = y;
```

Is there a way to do this for multiple columns of the matrix `X` such as

```
mat X(nrow, ncol);
mat Y(X.Multiple_colptr(0, 3), nrow, false, true);
    X.cols(0, 3) = Y;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the subsetting options in Armadillo eg https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat

Comment: I know the subsetting options. However, I wonder if it is possible to do this subsetting with a `.colptr()`  like operation.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. You are inquiring _entirely_ about features _of the upstream datatype_ and I humbly point out that you should consult the upstream documentation, in this case maybe for a different constructor.  The `RcppArmadillo` package happily brings an Armadillo matrix, however constructed, back and forth.  In short you have an `armadillo` question, not an `RcppArmadillo` one.  Happy to help, but ball is not exactly in my courtyard.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done directly with `colptr`. Pointers can be offset: `*(pointer + offset) == pointer[offset]`. So a simple way to achieve the functionality you want in `multiple_colptr` would be to offset a simple `colptr`. Consider this example (and run it yourself):

```
mat a = mat(2, 2, arma::fill::randn);
vec b = vec(a.colptr(0), a.n_cols * a.n_rows);
```

All the entries in `a` will copied to form a 4 element `vec` in `b`. You can obtain any number of columns by varying the pointer from `a.colptr(0)` and the number of elements to copy (Armadillo follows column-major ordering).

To copy part of a matrix into another you could use

```
mat a = mat(3, 3, arma::fill::randn);
mat b = mat(a.colptr(1), a.n_rows, 2);
```

Whilst this is possible, there is probably a better way of doing this with Aramdillo functions. The above example does not include bounds checking.